# Way to add hyperlink to Leaflet popup in Shiny

Tags: r, csv, popup, shiny, leaflet

Using `leaflet` in `shiny` to make an interactive map. Pulling data for popups from a CSV:

```
Row on CSV:
Name    lat          lng
Tufts   42.349598   -71.063541
```

Code on R for markers:

```
m %>% addMarkers(~lng, ~lat, icon = custommarker1 popup = ~htmlEscape(Name))
```

This returns marker in correct spot with popup displaying '`tufts`'

Wondering if there is a way to encode a hyperlink into the popup directly in the CSV?Oor to put plain text as a new CSV column and have `R`/`Shiny` then turn it into a hyperlink.

Very new to `shiny`/`leaflet` and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just include the link in the popup as html:

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
m <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
  addMarkers(lng=174.768, lat=-36.852, popup= '<a href = "https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/"> R </a>')
m  # Print the map
})
```

You can set the popup equal to a column in your dataframe as well. If your dataframe was called df and it contained longitude = long, latitude= lat, and urls = link :

```
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
m <- leaflet() %>%
addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
addMarkers(lng=df$long, lat=df$lat, popup= df$link)
m  # Print the map
```

})

Comment: Glad it worked. You are encouraged to mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the link to be a hyperlink, I have used this

`popup = ~paste("<a href=\"", link , "\">", "click here", "</a>")`

provided your data has a column called `link` where the urls are.

Comment: super helpful to get the construction of the `<a href` listed out. Thanks