# R Shiny app: create hyperlink to new dashboard window using leaflet popup

Tags: r, hyperlink, shiny, r-leaflet

Does someone know if it is possible to create links from leaflet selected items opening dedicated dashboards?

**Please find below a reproductible example**

When the user clicks on "Go to dedicated dashboard", I would like that my app opens a new window with a dedicated dashboard ( showing for instance charts related to the selected country ...)

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

# download zip file
download.file(url = "http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip", destfile = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip")

# unzip 
unzip( zipfile = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.zip" )

# transfrom to sf and select two countries
world.borders <-read_sf( dsn = getwd(), layer = "TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3" )
world.borders <- world.borders[world.borders$NAME %in% c("Australia","United States"),]


ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("mymap")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(options = leafletOptions(maxZoom = 18)) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addPolygons( data = world.borders, fill =  "#D24618", color = "#D24618",
                    popup = paste0(
                     "<b>Country: </b>"
                     , world.borders$NAME
                     , "<br>"
                     , "<a href='"
                     , "' target='_blank'>"
                     , "Go to dedicated dashboard</a>")
                     , label = ~NAME)
                  }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any tipps would be very appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700868/way-to-add-hyperlink-to-leaflet-popup-in-shiny) will show you how to do it. You just need your dedicated dashboard to have his own URL.